# Generate Animated Gif from Blobs and render in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, animated-gif, rmagick

I am trying to render an animated Gif from a controller action like this:

```
send_file data, type: 'image/gif', disposition: 'inline'
```

where data is equal to a blob output from rmagick. The image renders fine, but it is not animated like I expect. I think it has something to do with the rmagick image generation, and not the send_file, because if I instead write the animated gif to disk from rmagick, and render that, it works like expected.

So, onto my rmagick code...

```
gif = Magick::ImageList.new
gif.from_blob *frames # frames is an array of image blobs
gif.delay = delay if delay
gif.iterations = iterations if iterations
gif.scene = scene if scene
gif.ticks_per_second = ticks_per_second if ticks_per_second
gif.to_blob
```

This returns a blob, but I'm not sure if it is returning a single frame, or if it is returning the complete animated gif as a blob. I think this may be my problem.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Did you have a look at the output to see if it's actually an animated GIF or not? It's anyone's guess here.

Comment: yes, i'm rendering it in a controller, and it does not animate. I tried downloading the file, and its only 3kb (seems too small for an animated gif). The output in console is not helpful as a blob looks something like this:
����JFIFKK��C  
v�{���,M��9)��+/��H�������B췩�AnR�$�Wk��

Comment: If you have access to the `file` command it will usually tell you what that is. That seems like a JPEG file.

Comment: Ah, that is a big nudge in the right direction I think. The initial images are jpg blobs. I guess I don't see a way to output rmajick blob as a specific filetype "http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/2.15.4/Magick/ImageList#to_blob-instance_method"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @tadman for pointing me in the right direction. The output format of blob is ambiguous and I assumed since I had multiple images, and all of the animation options, that it would output a gif.

I found a post somewhere that someone needed to output the blob as a specific format (png) and was able to adapt the same usage.

this works for me:

```
gif.to_blob { |attrs| attrs.format = 'gif' }
```